# Python Typing: Generic Type that has the same interface as the wrapper type

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I would like to define a sort of "wrapper" Generic Type, say `MyType[T]`, so that it has the same type interface as the wrapped type.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyType(Generic):
    pass  # what to write here?
```

So, as an example, when I have a type `MyType[int]`, the type-checker should treat it as if it was an `int` type.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm, you're looking at wanting the expression `MyType[T]` to mean to a static type checker "A subclass of `MyType` and `T`", such that a declaration

```py
class MyType:
    attr: object
```

will result in the following (e.g. using mypy and [`int.conjugate`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/48d4f7a6a5ceac32c84401874b9be3d76edf9b61/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L238) as an example):

```
>>> reveal_type(MyType[int].conjugate)  # def (self: builtins.int) -> builtins.int
>>> obj: MyType[int] = MyType[int]()
>>> reveal_type(obj.attr)  # builtins.object
```

---

No, this isn't a supported idiom in Python typing. Your use case should be covered by a future implementation of [intersection types](https://github.com/CarliJoy/intersection_examples/issues) with a proposed syntax `MyType & T` instead.

To a static type checker, the syntax `MyType[T]` means *and only means* that `MyType` is a [generic type](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/generics.html) (including [generic structural types](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/generics.html#generic-protocols)), and the API that `MyType` has is derived from any metaclasses, any base classes, and anything declared under `class MyType`'s body.

- Any type parameterisation (e.g. passing `int` to `T` in `MyType[T]`) only affects generic types in the class bases and statements in the class body;
- There is nothing you can write in a class body which tells a static type checker that the class inherits the API from another class, as this information is already given by the metaclass and base class(es);
- `<type>[T]` is only well-defined as a *statically-inferrable type* when `<type>` is a user-defined generic type. The static types inferred from other arbitrary attempts to make `<type>[T]` a valid expression is unstable and implementation-defined, regardless of the runtime implementation.

  ```py
  from typing import *

  T = TypeVar("T")

  class M(type):
      def __getitem__(cls, type_: T, /) -> T: ...

  class A(metaclass=M): ...
  class B:
      def __class_getitem__(cls, type_: T, /) -> T: ...
  class C(Generic[T]): ...
  ```

  ```
  >>> A_int: TypeAlias = A[int]  # mypy: "A" expects no type arguments, but 1 given  # pyright: Expected no type arguments for class "A"
  >>> B_int: TypeAlias = B[int]  # mypy: "B" expects no type arguments, but 1 given  # pyright: <no messages>
  >>> C_int: TypeAlias = C[int]
  >>>
  >>> reveal_type(A[int])  # mypy: <overloads of `int.__new__`>                           pyright: Type of "A[int]" is "Type[int]"
  >>> reveal_type(B[int])  # mypy: The type "type[B]" is not generic and not indexable    pyright: Type of "B[int]" is "Type[int]"
  >>> reveal_type(C[int])  # mypy: Revealed type is "def () -> __main__.C[builtins.int]"  pyright: Type of "C[int]" is "Type[C[int]]"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the core of what you're looking for. If so, I'm happy to revise this answer, but if you want a new type to be type-checked the same as its base type, consider:

```py
MyType = int

a: MyType = 1
```

Running `b = a + 1` produces no linting errors, but `c = a + "a"` should raise a warning. Something to the extent of: `Operator "+" not supported for types "Literal[1]" and "Literal['a']"`

I'm not sure there's a need to create a whole new Generic class if you want the new type to behave just like an `int` (in this example)

Comment: That is a nice answer to a different question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to present this as an answer, just as an assumption (pls comment if I understood you incorrectly):

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyType(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T):
        self.value = value

# Example usage
x: MyType[int] = MyType(42)
y: MyType[str] = MyType("Hello")

# The type checker will treat x.value as an int and y.value as a str
reveal_type(x.value)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
reveal_type(y.value)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
```