# Mypy Plugin for Replacing Custom TypeAlias with NotRequired

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typing

I want to write a mypy plugin in order to introduce a type alias for `NotRequired[Optional[T]]`. (As I found out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77954574/generic-type-alias-for-notrequired-and-optional), it is not possible to write this type alias in plain python, because `NotRequired` is not allowed outside of a `TypedDict` definition.)

My idea is to define a generic `Possibly` type, like so:

```py
# possibly.__init__.py

from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Possibly(Generic[T]):
    pass
```

I then want my plugin to replace any occurrence of `Possibly[X]` with `NotRequired[Optional[X]]`. I tried the following approach:

```py
# possibly.plugin

from mypy.plugin import Plugin


class PossiblyPlugin(Plugin):
    def get_type_analyze_hook(self, fullname: str):
        if fullname != "possibly.Possibly":
            return
        return self._replace_possibly

    def _replace_possibly(self, ctx):
        arguments = ctx.type.args
        breakpoint()


def plugin(version):
    return PossiblyPlugin
```

At the breakpoint, I understand I have to construct an instance of a subclass of `mypy.types.Type`  based on `arguments`. But I didn't find a way to construct `NotRequired`. There is no corresponding type in `mypy.types`. I figure this might be due to the fact that `typing.NotRequired` is not a class, but a `typing._SpecialForm`. (I guess this is because `NotRequired` does not affect the value type, but the definition of the `.__optional_keys__` of the `TypedDict` it occurs on.)

So, then I thought about a different strategy: I could check for `TypedDict`s, see which fields are marked `Possibly`, and set the `.__optional_keys__` of the `TypedDict` instance to make the field not required, and replace the `Possibly` type by `mypy.types.UnionType(*arguments, None)`. But I didn't find which method on `mypy.plugin.Plugin` to use in order to get the `TypedDict`s into the context.

So, I am stuck. It is the first time I dig into the internals of `mypy`. Could you give me some direction how to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt (to construct an instance of subclass of `mypy.types.Type`) was correct - mypy simply calls it `mypy.types.RequiredType`, and `NotRequired` is specified as an instance state through the constructor like this: `mypy.types.RequiredType(<type>, required=False)`.

Here's an initial attempt at an implementation of `_replace_possibly`:

```py
def _replace_possibly(ctx: mypy.plugin.AnalyzeTypeContext) -> mypy.types.Type:
    """
    Transform `possibly.Possibly[<type>]` into `typing.NotRequired[<type> | None]`. Most
    of the implementation is copied from
    `mypy.typeanal.TypeAnalyser.try_analyze_special_unbound_type`.

    All `set_line` calls in the implementation are for reporting purposes, so that if
    any errors occur, mypy will report them in the correct line and column in the file.
    """

    if len(ctx.type.args) != 1:
        ctx.api.fail(
            "possibly.Possibly[] must have exactly one type argument",
            ctx.type,
            code=mypy.errorcodes.VALID_TYPE,
        )
        return mypy.types.AnyType(mypy.types.TypeOfAny.from_error)

    # Disallow usage of `Possibly` outside of `TypedDict`. Note: This check uses
    # non-exposed API, but must be done, because (as of mypy==1.8.0) the plugin will
    # otherwise crash.
    type_analyser: mypy.typeanal.TypeAnalyser = ctx.api  # type: ignore[assignment]
    if not type_analyser.allow_required:
        ctx.api.fail(
            "possibly.Possibly[] can only be used in a TypedDict definition",
            ctx.type,
            code=mypy.errorcodes.VALID_TYPE,
        )
        return mypy.types.AnyType(mypy.types.TypeOfAny.from_error)

    # Make mypy analyse `<type>` and get the analysed type
    analysed_type = ctx.api.analyze_type(ctx.type.args[0])
    # Make a new instance of a `None` type context to represent `None` in the union
    # `<type> | None`
    unionee_nonetype = mypy.types.NoneType()
    unionee_nonetype.set_line(analysed_type)
    # Make a new instance of a union type context to represent `<type> | None`.
    union_type = mypy.types.UnionType((analysed_type, unionee_nonetype))
    union_type.set_line(ctx.type)
    # Make the `NotRequired[<type> | None]` type context
    not_required_type = mypy.types.RequiredType(union_type, required=False)
    not_required_type.set_line(ctx.type)
    return not_required_type
```

[Your compliance tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77954574/generic-type-alias-for-notrequired-and-optional) in action:

```py
import typing_extensions as t

import possibly

class Struct(t.TypedDict):
    possibly_string: possibly.Possibly[str]
```

```
>>> non_compliant: Struct = {"possibly_string": int}  # mypy: Incompatible types (expression has type "type[int]", TypedDict item "possibly_string" has type "str | None") [typeddict-item]
>>> compliant_absent: Struct = {}  # OK
>>> compliant_none: Struct = {"possibly_string": None}  # OK
>>> compliant_present: Struct = {"possibly_string": "a string, indeed"}  # OK
```

---

Notes:

- mypy's plugin system is powerful but not thoroughly undocumented. The easiest way to go through mypy's internals, for the purposes of writing a plugin, is to use an existing type construct **incorrectly**, look at what string or string pattern is used in the error message, then attempt to find mypy's implementation using the string/pattern. For example, the following is an incorrect usage of `typing.NotRequired`:

  ```py
  from typing_extensions import TypedDict, NotRequired

  class A(TypedDict):
      a: NotRequired[int, str]  # mypy: NotRequired[] must have exactly one type argument
  ```

  You can find this message [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/517f5aee23ba218f615bcd4427bca62f120bc222/mypy/typeanal.py#L652-L665), which indicates that, despite `typing.NotRequired` not being a class, mypy models it as a type like any other generic, possibly because of ease of analysing the AST.
- Your plugin code's organisation is currently this:

  ```
  possibly/
    __init__.py
    plugin.py
  ```

  When mypy loads your plugin, any runtime code in `possibly.__init__` is loaded with the plugin, because mypy will import `possibly` when it tries to load the entry point `possibly.plugin.plugin`. All runtime code, including any which may be pulled from third-party packages, will be loaded every time `mypy` is run. I don't think this is desirable unless you can guarantee that your package is lightweight and has no dependencies.

  In fact, as I'm writing this, I realised that numpy's mypy plugin ([`numpy.typing.mypy_plugin`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/typing/mypy_plugin.py)) loads numpy (a big library!) because of this organisation.

  There are ways around this without having to separate the plugin directory from the package - you'll have to implement something in `__init__` which tries to not load any runtime subpackages if it's called by mypy.

Comment: I hope I can benefit from the additional Notes, the first one is most helpful in my situation. I think I already have another idea for a mypy plugin (to solve another problem unsolvable in python typing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77240105/python-typing-generic-type-that-has-the-same-interface-as-the-wrapper-type). Thanks for the inspiration and guidance!

Comment: @JonathanScholbach you're welcome. Regarding that other question, I don't think a mypy plugin was immediately something I would reach for, mainly because (1) an intersection typing solution is in the works (although ...who knows how long that would take) and (2) I didn't see anything obvious that existed in mypy's code base that would allow you to intersect a concrete type and a type variable. If you wanted to go ahead anyway, [this package](https://github.com/klausweiss/typing-protocol-intersection) may have some ideas you can start off with.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach if you're looking for intersection types, I'd recommend to start with https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy: this fork includes, among other features, Intersection types. You may use it as a starting point or perhaps just as a drop-in `mypy` replacement.

Comment: @STerliakov Thanks for the suggestion! What does it mean to be "based"?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach it's used here as a slang word that adds additional wordplay with "baseline", it means some sort of approval or that X is courageous, you'd better ask UrbanDictionary about details. (to be clear, I'm **not** the author of that fork, zero affiliation, I just know it exists and is well maintained).