What does `get_type_analyze_hook` return in a MyPy plugin that handles subtypes created by __class_getitem__ and recapitulate the __subclasshook__?
(NB: repost of a question that was deemed not specific enough and then auto-deleted before I got a chance to revise it)
Background tl;dr
I contribute to a scientific worklow engine called Pydra, which utilises Python typing annotations to provide dynamic type-checking at workflow construction time. It also uses these annotations to know which inputs are are files/directories so their contents can be included in hashes used in the internal cache.
Addressing some issues we were having dealing copying around file formats with separate headers led me to write a package for validating/handling different file formats, FileFormats. This also enabled us to include format-validation as part of the dynamic type-checking and register standard converters between some format types.
In this package I started using __class_getitem__ to specify additional information about the contents of the files, e.g. Gzip[Png] a PNG file that has been gzipped, without reading the warnings about it not being recommended outside the stdlib. However, it has proved to work really well for dynamic typing and I have started using it fairly widely, e.g. DicomSeries[Brain, T1Weighted] a dicom series containing T1-weighted MRI images of a brain. A __subclasshook__ is implemented in a mixin class that handles these cases where DicomSeries[Brain, T1Weighted] is considered a subclass of DicomSeries[Brain], DicomSeries[T1Weighted] and DicomSeries.
So I'm really quite happy with how the package works, but... then I tried to see if I could get it to work with static type-checking, specifically Mypy, and found out that I had drifted into the weeds of unrecommended/supported functionality in using __class_getitem__ for this purpose.
My question
So, what I want to know is how to write a plugin with get_type_analyze_hook to quash the warnings about using __class_getitem__ for non-generics and to recapitulate the rules in my subclass hook. I didn't get much out of reading the docs for get_type_analyze_hook, what is it meant to do? Do I just need to get it to return a valid type, can I use the logic in my code to do this?

There might be a misconception here. mypy is incidentally written in Python, but that doesn't mean you import mypy from your library or vice-versa - mypy is not supposed to use the logic in your code to do anything or share the same runtime at all. The mypy plugin runs when you add the plugin module name or file path to the configuration file's plugins option.

I thought that, but then I got a little confused trying to understand the numpy mypy plugin. What is the hook returned by get_type_analyze_hook meant to do?

The mypy runtime session builds its own abstract syntax tree by analysing the code source file. Each node in the AST represents an element of the Python typing system as modelled by mypy (statements, expressions, type expressions, etc.). Each node also contains line and column information so that when there is a static typing error, mypy correctly reports the location of that error in the source code.

... Your user-defined hook returned from get_type_analyze_hook takes an AST node representing a type expression which mypy hasn't yet analysed a type for, such as DicomSeries[Brain, T1Weighted], and allows you to tell mypy what type that it's supposed to be. The return value of your hook is an AST node - a type expression which is what you decided the type should be.

Briefly looking at the source code (such as numpy's typing plugin) is not enough to understand how it works. I suggest you install a non-compiled version of mypy (pip install mypy --no-binary mypy), then launch mypy as a Python process whilst putting a breakpoint at a plugin hook like numpy's. Inspect the object which numpy's hook actually returns. StackOverflow also has some other questions on mypy plugins (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22mypy+plugin%22), some of which have self-contained mypy plugin examples, that you should look at.

Thanks a lot for the suggestion @dROOOze, I will give the non-compiled version a go and step through. I had a look through the list of questions but I still can't find a good example of get_type_analyze_hook and what it is meant to return, do you know of any off the top of your head? Is the hook meant to return a stub class corresponding to the generated type?

Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77968372
